# Groovy List: Group by by a list of elements

Tags: dictionary, groovy, collections

I basically want to group maps, I must group by car and color and sums its prices, if any of the groups prices are greater than 25, group the result by car, color and motor and multiply the sum * 3, first part it's completed, but I'm stuck at the second group by:

```
def row1 = ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'C', "price": 12]
def row2 = ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'C', "price": 12]
def row3 = ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'D', "price": 2]
def row4 = ["car":'B',"color":'B',"motor":'D', "price": 13]
def arrayRows = []
arrayRows.add(row1)
arrayRows.add(row2)
arrayRows.add(row3)
arrayRows.add(row4)
println(arrayRows) //[[car:A, color:B, motor:C, price:12], [car:A, color:B, motor:C, price:12], [car:A, color:B, motor:D, price:2], [car:B, color:B, motor:D, price:13]]
def groups = arrayRows.groupBy {row -> [Car:row.car, Color:row.color] }.collect{k , v ->
    [
        car:k.Car,
        color:k.Color,
        motor:v.motor,
        price:v.collect { it.price }.sum()
    ]
}
println(groups) //[[car:A, color:B, motor:[C, C, D], price:26], [car:B, color:B, motor:[D], price:13]]
for(group in groups){
    if (group.price > 25){ //26>25
        println group //[car:A, color:B, motor:[C, C, D], price:26]
        //def groupByCarColorMotor = arrayRows.groupBy {[Car: group.car, Color: group.color, Motor:?]} | Must group by car, color and motor, and multiply * 3 it's price but since motor is an array, I'm not sure how to do so, I've tried groupBy { row -> group.it.motor} etc
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to group by the second time if I have:
[car:A, color:B, motor:[C, C, D]
And I should group by by:
[car:A, color:B, motor:C]
And
[car:A, color:B, motor:D]

**Expected output should be: 
[ ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'C', "price": 72, ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'D', "price": 6] ]**

Edit;
I almost managed to do it, the problem is that I'm getting an array of arrays of maps, and also you will probably get the idea behind it too.

```
def arrayRows = [ 
        ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'C', "price": 12],
        ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'C', "price": 12],
        ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'D', "price": 2],
        ["car":'B',"color":'B',"motor":'D', "price": 13]
        ]

println(arrayRows) //[[car:A, color:B, motor:C, price:12], [car:A, color:B, motor:C, price:12], [car:A, color:B, motor:D, price:2], [car:B, color:B, motor:D, price:13]]
def groups = arrayRows.groupBy {row -> [Car:row.car, Color:row.color] }.collect{k , v ->
    [
            car:k.Car,
            color:k.Color,
            price:v.collect { it.price }.sum()
    ]
}.findAll{it.price > 25}

def groupByCarColor = []
for (group in groups){
    groupByCarColor.add(arrayRows.findAll{ row -> row.car == group.car && row.color == group.color}.groupBy {row -> [Car:group.car, Color:group.color, Motor:row.motor] }.collect{k , v ->
        [
                car:k.Car,
                color:k.Color,
                motor:k.Motor,
                price:v.collect { it.price }.sum()*3
        ]
    })
}
```

Output: [[[car:A, color:B, motor:C, price:72], [car:A, color:B, motor:D, price:6]]]

Comment: What is the result for a group, that does not have more than 25 in sum of prices?

Comment: @cfrick We shouldn't consider these for the second group part. If there are non, output should be an empty array. This would happen to ["car":'B',"color":'B',"motor":'D', "price": 13] since the sum of prices of all cars, and colors (B, B) don't sum more than 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal here is to find the groups via a triplet - but you want to filter out those groups where a predicate fails on a subgroup.  E.g.

```
def arrayRows = [ 
    [car:'A', motor:'C', color:'B',price: 12],
    [car:'A', motor:'C', color:'B',price: 12],
    [car:'A', motor:'D', color:'B',price:  2],
    [car:'B', motor:'D', color:'B',price: 13],
]


def output = arrayRows.inject([:].withDefault{ 0 }){ acc, row -> // group by the triplet and sum up the price
    acc[row.subMap(['car','motor','color'])]+=row.price; acc
}.groupBy{ k, _ -> // group by the filter criteria tuple
    k.subMap(['car','color'])
}.findAll{ _, v -> // eliminate the tuple-groups where price is to low
    v.values().sum() > 25
}.collectMany{ _, vs -> // reshape the data
    vs.collect{ k, v ->
        k + [price: v * 3]
    }
}

assert output==[[car:"A", motor:"C", color:"B", price:72], [car:"A", motor:"D", color:"B", price:6]]
```

Comment: This was basically it, comments were also super helpful and naming the goal I wanted to achieve was also helpful! Thank you! I have another question and I'm not sure if I should edit this question or create another one, how could I do it if I have another parameter in a map, example: 
[car:'A', motor:'C', color:'B',price: 15, parameter: "hi"],  
[car:'A', motor:'C', color:'B',price: 11, parameter: "hi"]. 
End result would be:
[car:'A', motor:'C', color:'B',price: 26, parameter: ["hi", "hi"]]
It seems to me that the first inject is a replacement for a groupBy to avoid the problem explained

Comment: You can replace the first step (which is a groupBy and the summing combined) with just a groupBy and then work from there. But another param begs the question of how to aggregate it in the grouping steps.  If it's just a constant you can add it in the first step of above pipeline (when the price get's added)

Answer (score 1):

Something straight-forward for your home assignment:

```
def arrayRows = [
["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'C', "price": 13],
["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'D', "price": 14],
["car":'B',"color":'B',"motor":'D', "price": 13],
]

List out = arrayRows.groupBy{ [ car:it.car, color:it.color ] }.inject( [] ){ List res, k, v ->
  if( 25 < v*.price.sum() ) v.each{ res << ( it + [ price:it.price * 3 ] ) }
  res
}

assert out.toString() == '[[car:A, color:B, motor:C, price:39], [car:A, color:B, motor:D, price:42]]'
```

Comment: Although the output is correct, imagine the following case: ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'C', "price": 13], ["car":'A',"color":'B',"motor":'C', "price": 14] Output should be: [[car:A, color:B, motor:C, price:81]] (13+14*3) So what I would is group by Car and Color, make the condition of 25, and groupBy again by Car, Color and Motor of the results of the first groupBy. Not sure if this is the only answer through. I changed the example